# Erro no código do echo da minha página

Tags: php

Estou a criar um sistema de pesquisa, mas na página onde vai fazer a pesquisa estou a receber erro no código na parte do `echo` e não estou a conseguir resolver.

```
<?php
$campo="%".$_POST['campo']."%";

$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para
WHERE raddb.Alertas.Para = '$colaborador' AND De like ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$campo);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($De,$Assunto,$Prioridade, $Data);

echo ' 
    <table class="table table-responsive">  
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;">De</th>
            <th width="60%" style="text-align:center;">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Recebido</th>                
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <thead>'
    <?php  

        do{

         if($nomede != $produto["De"]){
    ?> ' 
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: '<?php echo $produto["Data"]; ?>'</th>
    '<?php
        $nomede = $produto["De"];
        }
   ?>'
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>  
        <td >'<?php echo $produto["De"]; ?>'</td>
        <td class="td-info view_data apagar" id="'<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>,<?php echo $produto["Para"]; ?>'" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" '<?php echo $produto["Status"] != '0'?' style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ':' style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" '?>'>'<?php echo $produto["Assunto"]; ?>'</td>  
        <td>'<?php echo $produto["Prioridade"]; ?>'</td> 
        <td>'<?php echo $produto["Hora"]; ?>'</td>
        </tr>

'<?php } while($produto = $sql->fetch_assoc()); ?>'
<tbody>
</table>
';

?>
```

No servidor apache retorna a seguinte mensagem do erro, mas não estou a perceber o porquê de dar este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, o problema está depois de montar o cabeçalho da tabela. Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```html
<?php
$campo="%".$_POST['campo']."%";

$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para
WHERE raddb.Alertas.Para = '$colaborador' AND De like ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$campo);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($De,$Assunto,$Prioridade, $Data);

echo ' 
    <table class="table table-responsive">  
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;">De</th>
            <th width="60%" style="text-align:center;">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Recebido</th>                
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <thead>';

        do{

         if($nomede != $produto["De"]){
    ?> ' 
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: '<?php echo $produto["Data"]; ?>'</th>
    '<?php
        $nomede = $produto["De"];
        }
   ?>'
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>  
        <td >'<?php echo $produto["De"]; ?>'</td>
        <td class="td-info view_data apagar" id="'<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>,<?php echo $produto["Para"]; ?>'" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" '<?php echo $produto["Status"] != '0'?' style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ':' style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" '?>'>'<?php echo $produto["Assunto"]; ?>'</td>  
        <td>'<?php echo $produto["Prioridade"]; ?>'</td> 
        <td>'<?php echo $produto["Hora"]; ?>'</td>
        </tr>

'<?php } while($produto = $sql->fetch_assoc()); ?>'
<tbody>
</table>
```